# Any Web Service which can tell me temperature with respect to latitude and longitude?

Tags: wcf, web-services

Do we have any web service that tells the approximate temperature by latitude and longitude?

Please help!.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api).

Here is the [example](http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=37.76834106,-122.39418793).